# How to disable anti-aliasing in git-gui and gitk

Tags: apt, package-management, fonts, git

After an upgrade to Tcl/Tk 8.5, `git-gui` and `gitk` are using anti-aliased fonts which look ugly on my display.  I can select different fonts in the preferences dialog, but the fonts I was using before (Helvetica and Courier bitmap fonts) don't seem to appear in the list.  How do I restore the previous fonts?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to solve this that doesn't involve re-compiling Tk, so I had to downgrade to Tcl/Tk 8.4.  Since the Debian package manager didn't let me do this (`git-gui` and `gitk` require current `tcl` and `tk` which conflict with `tcl8.4` and `tk8.4`), I ended up manually backing up the 8.4 files and copying them back after the upgrade, which is obviously a terrible solution.

I'd be happy to know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a fontconfig file like so:

```
mkdir .config/fontconfig/
touch .config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
```

Open the newly created `fonts.conf` file in your text editor of choice, and paste or type:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="autohint" >
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba" >
   <const>none</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting" >
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle" >
   <const>hintslight</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias" >
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

[image: git gui without antialiasing]